# Model.find({}) returns empty even though there are documents in the Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am able to write to the `users` collection using my '/sign-up' route - that works fine, but I cannot read **all** the documents from the **users** collection. All I get back is an empty array

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "results": 0,
    "data": {
        "users": []
    }
}
```

In mongo shell I am able to get back all the users like `db.users.find().pretty()`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f95ad29c2b3fc4f1876bb83"),
        "role" : "student",
        "photo" : "default.jpg",
        "active" : true,
        "name" : "Orion POC",
        "email" : "vega@example.com",
        "password" : "$2a$12$xpO3cloW5H.n650i0xQXEuaZOfdvTt43Y2dkMxrY5K8zfGfPIUYEO",
        "passwordChangedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-25T16:51:52.600Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Solution Tried

- I have added collection as an property in the second argument that you can pass in mongoose.Schema() to make it target the pluraised collection name - because `utils.toCollectionName`

I am honestly at wits end here, I don't know what the problem is, and its the same for other Collections as well

**models/userModel.js**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'You must have a name'],
      minlength: [5, 'A name must have more than 5 characters'],
      maxlength: [30, 'A name cannot have more than 30 characters'],
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'You must have an email'],
      maxlength: [50, 'The email entered is too long'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Your email is not valid'],
    },

    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['student', 'parent', 'teacher'],
      default: 'student',
    },

    photo: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default.jpg',
    },

    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'You must give a password'],
      minlength: [
        8,
        'Your password is too short, you must enter more than 8 characters',
      ],
      validate: [
        function (val) {
          const regex = RegExp('^[-\\w@!$£%^&*+]+$');
          return regex.test(val);
        },
        'Non-special characters are not allowed, please use a mix of letters and numbers',
      ],
      select: false,
    },

    passwordConfirm: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
      minlength: [
        8,
        'Your password is too short, you must enter more than 8 characters',
      ],
      validate: [
        function (val) {
          return val === this.password;
        },
        'Password do not match',
      ],
      select: false,
    },

    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
      select: false,
    },

    // Field is only given to a user when they have changed their password, if not this field will not exist in the user document
    passwordChangedAt: Date,
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    collection: 'users',
  }
);

// SCHEMA MIDDLEWARE

// hash password
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // hash and salt password with cost of 12
  this.password = await bcryptjs.hash(this.password, 12);

  // delete passwordConfirm field
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;

  next();
});

// create timestamp for a changed password
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Subtract 1000ms for error margins
  this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
  next();
});

// Retrieve only active users
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.find({ active: { $ne: true } });
  next();
});

// INSTANCE METHODS

// Password checker
userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function (
  inputPassword,
  userPassword
) {
  return await bcryptjs.compare(inputPassword, userPassword);
};

// Check if the password has been modified
userSchema.methods.modifiedPassword = function (JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimeStamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );

    // Password HAS been changed
    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimeStamp;
  }
  // Password has NOT been changed
  return false;
};

// Set the passwordResetToken
userSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = function () {
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  this.passwordResetToken = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest('hex');

  // console.log({ resetToken }, this.passwordResetToken);

  this.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**controllers/userController.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const User = require('../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const factory = require('./handlerFactory');

exports.getAllUsers = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const users = await User.find({});
  console.log(users);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    results: users.length,
    data: {
      users,
    },
  });
});
```

**routes/userRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

// ROUTING
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/sign-up', authController.signup);

router.get('/', userController.getAllUsers);

router.get('/:id', userController.getUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const hpp = require('hpp');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const compression = require('compression');

const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController');
const AppError = require('./utils/appError');

const app = express();

// app.use(
//   cors({
//     origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
//     credentials: true,
//   })
// );

// SET Security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());
// app.use(
//   helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
//     directives: {
//       defaultSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'data:', 'ws:'],
//       baseUri: ["'self'"],
//       fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'data:'],
//       imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data'],
//       scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'blob:'],
//       styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https:', 'http:'],
//     },
//   })
// );

// dev logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// Limit number of requests from the same IP
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!',
});

app.use('/api', limiter);

// body parser, reading data from body into req.body
// middleware that sits in the middle of req(uests) and res(ponse) - we do this to get access to the body of a HTTP request
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injections
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

// Protect against request parameter pollution
app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: [
      'duration',
      'ratingsQuantity',
      'ratingsAverage',
      'maxGroupSize, ',
      'difficulty',
      'price',
    ],
  })
);

// TO COMPRESS ALL INCOMING TEXT REQUEST AND COMPRESS THEM USING GZIP ETC.
app.use(compression());

// ROUTES
app.use('/api/v0/users', userRouter);

// UNHANDLED ROUTE ERROR MIDDLEWARE
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 400));
});

// GLOBAL ERROR HANDLER MIDDLEWARE: SIGNATURE (ERROR, REQ, RES, NEXT)
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

**server.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// CATCH ERRORS THAT ARE NOT PROMISE RELATED
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Shutting down...');
  // console.log(err.stack);
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

// READ IN ENV VARS INTO SERVER
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app');

// PLACE PASSWORD IN MONGO CONNECTION STRING
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

// CONNECT TO CLOUD MONGODB
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoIndex: true,
  })
  .then((con) => console.log('DB Connection Successful'));

// START SERVER
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});

// CATCH UNHANDLED PROMISES
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION! Shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});

// FOR HEROKU ON THEIR 24/7 SIGTERM SIGNAL
// process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
//   console.log(' SIGTERM RECEIVED. Shutting down gracefully...');
//   server.close(() => {
//     console.log(' Process terminated!');
//   });
// });
```

Comment: There is a ton of code in this question that doesn't seem relevant for the problem you are trying to solve. Can you please trim it down to just the minimal code needed to reproduce it?

Comment: In the `.pre(/^find/)` middleware, shouldn't it be `$eq: true` instead of `$ne: true`? Doesn't it currently only find those where `active` is _not equal_ to `true`?

Comment: Welcome! Please use this link to make your question understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the comments - it my first time writing a question to Stackoverflow. I am sorry for the very long code snippets - I will try to look at the minimal code example and in the future post questions like that.

I re-wrote the code for my Users, I literally re-wrote it code-for-code, and magically like that, User.find() worked.

I am sorry for the waste of time anyone had got from this.